# How to show that (P & Q) v (~P v ~ Q) is a theorem in SD

Tags: logic, symbolic-logic

I’m working on a practice question on my logic textbook. And I’m stuck at this question.

This is what I have so far:

```
1. ~(P & Q)   Assumption/ Negated Eelimination 
2.     P          Assumption/Negated Introduction 
3.       Q          Assumption/Negated Introduction 
4.       P&Q        2,3 conjunction Introduction
5.     ~(P&Q)       1 Reteration 
6.    ~Q            2-5 Negated Introduction
```

Now, as long as I can derive a Q, then I will be able to Derive (P&Q)
I’m wondering if some one can give me some insight.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Isn't this just logic, not philosophy of logic or logic with any philosophical dimension ?

Comment: Can't you use de Morgan? Just open the brackets of NAND part.

Comment: So this *is* philosophy of logic or logic with a philosophical dimension ? Interesting.

Comment: What is the question that you are stuck on and what is the name of the logic book you are using.  Do you use any software for proof checking?

Comment: As you can see from the answers below, the details depend on the proof systems you are allowed to use: if, e.g. SD is Natural Deduction, you have not a "prinmitive rule" for De Morgan. You have to use instead Double Negation. So, please, specify what system SD stands for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You won’t be able to prove either disjunct, as neither is a logical truth. Instead, assume the negation of what you want to prove and then derive a contradiction. I’m sure others can format this much more beautifully than I can, but here’s a proof. I use ‘F’ to mean the falsum/contradiction and I rely on a DeMorgan equivalence, but this, of course, be eliminated.

|1. ~((P&Q)∨(~P∨~Q))........Assume
||2. P&Q................................Assume
||3. (P&Q)∨(~P∨~Q)...........2, ∨Intro
||4. F          ...................................      1,3
|5. ~(P&Q)..........................            2-4, ~Intro
|6. ~P ∨ ~Q........................            5,DeMorgan
|7. (P&Q)∨(~P∨~Q)..........     6, ∨Intro
|8. F....................................                 1,7
9. (P&Q)∨(~P∨~Q)..........      1-8, ~Elim

Answer (score 6):

another approach giving the minimum number of steps (though not a formal proof):

```
1. (P & Q) v ~(P & Q)              law of excluded middle
2. (P & Q) v (~P v ~Q)             DeM 1
```

Answer (score 3):

Using the [natural deduction and proof checker](http://proofs.openlogicproject.org/) associated with *[forall x: Calgary Remix](http://forallx.openlogicproject.org/)*, I get the following proof:

[image]

In line 1 begin a subproof by assuming the negation of what you want to prove.

In line 2 apply DeMorgan's rule to line 1.

In line 3 eliminate the first part of the conjunction in line 2.

In line 4 apply DeMorgan's rule to line 3.

In line 5 eliminate the second part of the conjunction in line 2.

In line 6 introduce a contradiction based on lines 4 and 5.

In line 7 discharge the assumption in line 1 and exit the subproof using indirect proof (IP) to reach the desired conclusion.

Answer (score 2):

I would like to offer the following "proof."

1 - If (A) V ~(A) is a SD theorem,
2 - A = (P & Q)           : definition
3 - (P & Q) V (~P V ~Q)   : given
4 - (P & Q) V ~(P & Q)    : DeMorgan (on 2nd part)
5 - (A) V ~(A)            : substitution
6 - Therefore (P & Q) V (~P V ~Q), **is** a SD theorem.

Answer (score 2):

Strategy: Demonstrate that assuming the target is false leads to a contradiction no matter what we assume about the literals.

The Fitch Style proof is as follows: Assume some stuff and, then, deny everything.  Basically.

```
   ._.
 1.|  |_ ~((p & q) v (~p v ~q))      : Assumption
 2.|  |  |_ p                        : Assumption
 3.|  |  |  |_ q                     : Assumption

 6.|  |  |  | #                      : Negation Elimination (1,5)
 7.|  |  | ~q                        : Negation Introduction (3-6)

10.|  |  | #                         : Negation Elimination (1,9)
11.|  | ~p                           : Negation Introduction(2-10)

14.|  | #                            : Negation Elimination (1,13)
15.| ~~((p & q) v (~p v ~q))         : Negation Introduction (1-14)
16.| ((p & q) v (~p v ~q))           : Double Negation Elimination (15)
```

Opps.  I missed a few steps. :)

NB: The DNE at the end suggests this is not a constructively valid theorem.  Indeed, it is not. Still ((p & q) v (~p v ~q)) is a theorem of classical logic, 
as shown by using only the basic rules of inference for natural deduction.

PS: Using # as the falsum constant

Answer (score 0):

No answer so far has been purely in SD.

1. |~((P&Q)∨(~P∨~Q))     A/~E
2. | ~P               A/~E
3. | (~Pv~Q)          2 vI
4. | (~Pv~Q)v(P&Q)    3 vI
5. | ~((P&Q)∨(~P∨~Q)) 1 R
6. |P                    2-5 ~E
7. | ~Q               A/~E
8. | (~Pv~Q)          7 vI
9. | (~Pv~Q)v(P&Q)    8 vI
10. | ~((P&Q)∨(~P∨~Q)) 1 R
11. |Q                   7-10 ~E
12. |(P&Q)
13. |(P&Q)v(~P∨~Q)       12 vI
14. |~((P&Q)∨(~P∨~Q))    1 R
15. (P&Q)∨(~P∨~Q)        1-14 ~E